# Owl Carousel can't drag (swipe via touch) to scroll on page when touching over carousel with Hammer js

Tags: scroll, swipe, drag, hammer.js, owl-carousel

Using **OWL carousel** (1, not the v.2 beta) I **can't swipe to scroll** through a page on mobile web when a carousel is present - that is, **when touching over the carousel** to scroll.

I've tried to modify the code, but can't figure out how to make it work!

Comment: So it looks like it was a problem I was having with **hammer.js** after all!
The solution in this post fixed it: [touch action fix](http://dailyjs.com/2014/05/20/hammerjs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem I was having was related with **hammer.js** and not with owl carousel.

I found the fix [here](http://dailyjs.com/2014/05/20/hammerjs/). What I just needed was to set the touchAction variable to "pan-y" instead of "none":

`Hammer.defaults.behavior.touchAction = 'pan-y';`